# Socket IO - On 'connection' function increments by one each time even after browser close

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to manage some user connections and assign them to rooms in a Google Chrome extension. I'm fairly new to sockets so maybe i've got the wrong idea of how they work but the documentation i've read online suggests i'm assuming correctly.

I have the following controller function on my express server that fires every time a user logs into the extension:

```
exports.connectWebsocket = (io) => {
  return function(req,res,next) {

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {  

      console.log("live connections:")
      console.log(Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets))

      for(let i=0;i<req.user.teams.length;i++) {
        socket.join(req.user.teams[i]);
      }

      io.sockets.in('my-room-id').emit('message',"Hello to this room")

      socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {  
        console.log('someone Disconnected')
      })      

    });

    next();
  }
}
```

Here is where i'm calling the controller

```
module.exports = function(io) {

  router.post('/login',
    authController.connectWebsocket(io),
    utilityController.respond
  );

  return router;

}
```

When I log into the app the first time I get the desired result. The function logs the live connections which is just one and when I close down my browser I get a console log of someone Disconected.

However, when I open the browser a second time and log into the app I get the io.on('connection') function firing twice. So the console.logs will look like this:

```
live connections:
[ 'e6hymsfaf9EPnYm-AAAE' ]
live connections:
[ 'e6hymsfaf9EPnYm-AAAE' ]
```

If I then close the browser I get someone Disconnected outputted twice. The same will happen if I go through the close browser, re-open and login again but this time everything will be logged 3 times, then 4 times and so on and so forth.

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, it seems that the sockets are disconnecting as they should but I can't understand why the on connection socket event is firing in increments of 1 every time.

Could someone please shed some light as to why?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you're calling `connectWebsocket()` every time someone hits the `/login` route.  And, `connectWebsocket()` contains `io.on('connection', ...)`.  So, that means that every time someone hits the `/login` route, you add yet another duplicate `io.on('connection', ...)` event handler.  That is definitely not what you want.  You want ONE `io.on('connection', ...)` handler, not added inside a route, but added once after your socket.io server is initialized.

Comment: That makes complete sense, let me try and let you know

Comment: If you want to post the answer i'll mark it as correct!